# What is the View Generating of EF

Tags: entity-framework

After I read [Performance Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx). I Have something not understand.

> Before the Entity Framework can execute a query against a conceptual model or save changes to the data source, it must generate a set of local query views to access the database. Because of the high cost of generating these views, you can pre-generate the views and add them to the project at design-time.

My first question is Does it means everytime before executing a query EF will generate views for it ?
Second questions is  What is the view? What is it used for ? Thanks

Comment: I think this is referring to EF generating a conceptual model of the database so that it can later generate queries based on the conceptual model. What's important to note is that this is only done once per appdomain which means unless you are having performance issues at app start this probably isn't an issue for you

Comment: Hi. My friend.Yes. I just known it happens once for each app domain.
In Performance Considerations I think the Query efficiency is the thing I should care about Firstly. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Query efficiency is definitely the thing which will provide the greatest benefit in most applications. I've done a bit of research into how EF performs and what scenarios it doesn't do well in, perhaps this would be a useful read? http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/03/entity-framework-comparative.html is an overview and its also worth taking a look at AsNoTracking http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html and AutoDetectChanges http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html